# A cleaner implementation rather than using LIKE

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains Email Domains separated by semi-colons.

```
Domain
------
gmail.com;googlemail.com
hotmail.com;hotmail.co.uk;live.co.uk
```

I am currently running the following SQL:

```
SELECT [Id]
  FROM [DomainGroup]
 WHERE [Domain] LIKE '%' + (SELECT RIGHT('anemail@gmail.com', CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE('anemail@gmail.com')) - 1)) + '%'
```

Although this is working, I was thinking that maybe using `PATINDEX` would be better, from both performance and readability.  The email address is actually a variable, but I've put it in to show what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Why not just normalize the column into a separate table? Your current like approach will say accept `hotmail.com` for `neil@hotmail.co` which might not be a big deal for your implementation but is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the performance benefit of `PATINDEX` vs `LIKE` is at best [ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052425/sql-string-comparison-speed-like-vs-patindex), particularly in your case given that normalizing the delimited values to individual rows in an indexed column would give more of a performance boost than anything else.

If you can't change design & want to use `PATINDEX`, then I would pre-compute the pattern;

```
declare @emaildomain varchar(128) = 'anemail@gmail.com'
set @emaildomain = '%;' + stuff(@emaildomain, 1, charindex('@', @emaildomain), '')  + ';%'
```

Then use that in the where clause;

```
where patindex(@emaildomain, ';' + [Domain] + ';') > 0
```

(I padded with `;` delimiters so `aaa@bbb.com` would not match `aaabbb.com;`)

Comment: Using this `PATINDEX`, I'd have to start the domains with `;`?

Comment: Same for LIKE; `%aaa.com` would match `xxxaaa.com` in `xxxaaa.com;bbb.com`  -  adding `;` ensures the test is `%;aaa.com;` in `;xxxaaa.com;bbb.com;` (i.e. no match in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using fulltext search?

After creating the index, queries would look like:

```
SELECT [Id] FROM [DomainGroup] WHERE CONTAINS ([Domain], 'gmail.com')
```