# How can I use like in a list for SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in a table that I want to search using like. For example

```
SELECT * from Employee
WHERE Employee.LName like ('%Mac%', '%Smi%', '%Wal%')
```

When I try that, it doesn't work. I'd like to be able to do something like that, rather than like

```
SELECT * from Employee
WHERE Employee.LName like '%Mac%'
OR Employee.LName like '%Smi%'
OR Employee.LName like '%Wal%'
```

Comment: Is your list of potential matches arbitrarily long? Is it dynamic? In either your "default" solution or @Sparky's with the temp table may be faster with PATINDEX then like.

Comment: The list of matches is going to be hardcoded in (and probably added to a little bit over time). I've never heard of PATINDEX.

Comment: Definitely look up PATINDEX (and CHARINDEX for that matter). One discussion of LIKE vs PATINDEX can be found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052425.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table #lookfor (LikeName varchar(32))
insert into #lookfor values ('%Mac%'),('%Smi%'),('%wal%')


select * 
from employee emp 
join #lookfor lf on emp.LastName like lf.Likename
```

- Build a temporary table to hold the expressions.
- Join your main table and #temp table using the LIKE operator

Comment: I've been really busy at work so haven't had time to try this yet, but I really like the simplicity of this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is easier but it is an option
It is nice if you need to mock up a join

```
  SELECT [docEnum1].[value]
    FROM [docEnum1]
    join ( values ('%new%'), ('%allen%'), ('%waste%')
         ) as [joinVals] (val)
      on [docEnum1].[value] like [joinVals].[val]
```

Comment: Not really that different from the below answer, right?

Comment: You mean the above accepted solution?  One it does not create a #temp table?  Really you think a solution with more code and #temp is simpler?  What if #lookfor is in use?

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server, you can do just the same w/o temp tables, but with the same simplicity, using a [table variable](https://www.sqlshack.com/the-table-variable-in-sql-server/):

```
DECLARE @lookfor TABLE (LikeName VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @lookfor(LikeName) VALUES ('%Mac%'),('%Smi%'),('%wal%');

SELECT * 
FROM employee emp 
JOIN @lookfor lf ON emp.LastName LIKE lf.Likename
```